# Hide Toolbar from Activity and custom toolbar in fragment

Tags: android

I want to hide toolbar in my fragment and display my own custom toolbar for that fragment.
ps. i have darkactionbar in styles.xml. after hiding and showing my own custom toolbar, here is the images. please help me out in this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6IsY.png)

before navigating to fragment - image 1
on fragment - image 2
closing fragment and returning to activity - image3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double Toolbar Is Showing on Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163374/double-toolbar-is-showing-on-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to hide the inbuilt toolbar -
Let's talk about all steps for Kotlin code:

- If you want to hide toolbar in Activity you can use -
  `actionBar?.hide`
- If you want to hide toolbar in Fragment you can use -
  `(requireActivity() as MainActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()`
- Another way is to change `DarkActionBar` to `NoActionBar` in your `themes.xml`

Now these were the ways by which you can disable inbuilt toolbar.
Next is to see how to create your own toolbar.

So simply in MainActivity xml create your design and add clicks to it in kt file.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  but toolbar is getting overlapped with activity toolbar

Comment: i found the solution, it is simple, getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);